# How to use cin with a variable number of inputs?

Tags: c++

I was in a programming competition yesterday and we had to read in input of the form

```
n
a1 a2 ... an
m
b1 b2 ... bm
...
```

where the first line says how many inputs there are, and the next line contains that many inputs (and all inputs are integers).

I know if each line has the same number of inputs (say 3), we can write something like

```
while (true) {
    cin >> a1 >> a2 >> a3;
    if (end of file)
        break;
}
```

But how do you do it when each line can have a different number of inputs?

Comment: What do you normally need to do when you need to repeat some operation a variable number of times?  And what kind of data structure would you use to store a variable number of items?

Comment: @ÖöTiib: My bad, I'll fix that.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Although OP did not make it clear, usually the input ends with a non-positive value for number of elements. So, OP should change the condition to be such.

Comment: As soon you are using cin (or a pipe) you have to specify a data format (what is a separator, what is a terminating character (maybe none just EOF), etc ...)

Comment: The overloaded `>>` operator does not read spaces or newline characters. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738882/read-input-separated-by-whitespaces-or-newline/5738922#5738922)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple take using just standard libraries:

```
#include <vector>       // for vector
#include <iostream>     // for cout/cin, streamsize
#include <sstream>      // for istringstream
#include <algorithm>    // for copy, copy_n
#include <iterator>     // for istream_iterator<>, ostream_iterator<>
#include <limits>       // for numeric_limits

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> contents;

    int number;
    while (std::cin >> number)
    {
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // skip eol
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        if (std::cin)
        {
            contents.emplace_back(number);
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<double>(iss), number, contents.back().begin());
        }
        else
        {
            return 255;
        }
    }

    if (!std::cin.eof())
        std::cout << "Warning: end of file not reached\n";

    for (auto& row : contents)
    {
        std::copy(row.begin(), row.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout," "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

See it **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7bab0413378a6decccff63436a820afc-b6fd1a44018564a0f0702b6beba187f3)**: input

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
7 
6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Comment: the 2nd `std::cin.ignore ()` will ignore `m` (ie. 7) which is why only 6 entries are present on the 2nd line of output.

Comment: @refp Whoops, that was a tad sloppy :/ Fixed, thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 3):

you can do it this way

```
#include<vector>
...
...
std::vector<sometype> a;
sometype b;
std::cin >> b;
while(std::cin)
{
 a.push_back(b);
 std::cin >> b;
}
```

you can input any number of items and when you are finished send in the EOF signal.

Answer (score 1):

Your Algorithm will look something like this:

```
1. read the 'number' of inputs, say n1
2. set up a loop to read the n1 inputs
3. check if the user has more inputs to give
   if YES repeat the steps 1,2 and 3 till all inputs are taken and stored.
   else move on...
```

You can use a for or while loop and store the inputs into an array.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Because people were complaining how I called my first answer "a simple take", here's a proper version using Boost Spirit:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> data_t;
    typedef boost::spirit::istream_iterator It;

    std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    It first(std::cin), last;

    bool ok;
    data_t contents;

    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        static rule<It, data_t(),                        blank_type, locals<int>> file;
        static rule<It, std::vector<double>(int number), blank_type>              row;

        _a_type number; // friendly alias

        file %= -(omit [int_[number=_1]] > eol > row(number)) % eol;
        row   = repeat(_r1) [ double_ ];

        ok = phrase_parse(first, last, file, blank, contents);
    }

    if (ok) for (auto& row : contents)
    {
        std::copy(row.begin(), row.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout," "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    if (first!=last)
        std::cout << "Warning: end of file not reached, remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";
}
```

It's obviously far superior

- it uses far fewer include lines :)
- it takes ~10x as long to compile (with no optimizations), another 16% longer with optimizations
- it requires about 5 years of study in meta-programming to grok it (joking, the spirit docs/tutorials are quite ok)
- on the serious account: it is much more flexible

  - can be extended to parse other structural elements, more complicated
  - can implement semantics on the fly
  - will parse NaN and +/-infinity correctly
  - etc.

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1768b5de3574367ff83a04198ee79c11-9ae2ed42feea604c62c8d5fb4cec0844) as well**

Answer (score 1):

Given the format you are specifying, here is what I would do.

```
for (int n; std::cin >> n; )
{
    if (n == 0)     // Test for end of input
        break;

    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    {
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
        if (!std::cin)
            break;

        // Valid input x. Now do something with x like
        // v.push_back(x) where v is some vector of ints
    }
}

// Did we succeed?
if (!std::cin)
{
    // Something went bad.
    std::cerr << "Error reading input" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use a for loop and array.

```
int a[MAX]; // programming problems usually specify a max size
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
cin>>a[i];
```

Comment: Why using raw array for this?

Comment: it's true that raw arrays are not a good programming practice, but I was demonstrating how input can be taken if total number of element varies from case to case.

Comment: -1. There is absolutely no reason why the number of possible input elements should be limited by the array's size.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Yes, I am aware of this. However, the OP asked in the context of programming contests and usually there is always a reasonable upper bound on input size.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using arrays and dynamic memory allocation for taking variable number of inputs of a predefined type.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n;
cout<<"Enter the number of elements"<<endl;
cin>>n;
int *c=new int[n];
for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    cin>>c[k];
delete c;
}
```