# How to prelevate an imprecision number of element from a file with fstream?

Tags: c++

I should read a text file which contain an imprecision number of lines with names of different car, follow by numbers of cars sold in the last 6 month. I don't know how to read the file without know the precise number of element that is content in it.

The file is like this:

```
Ferrari       3  7  5  4  1  3
Porsche      10 11 12 13 10 11
Lamborghini   1  8  2  3  4  1
...
...
```

I know that I must use the "fstream" library, but after the file opening, i don't know what i should do.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
fstream file;
file.open("nomefile.txt", ios::in);

...

return 0;
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408761/how-to-use-cin-with-a-variable-number-of-inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::getline()` in a loop, using `std::istringstream` to parse each line, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("nomefile.txt");
    std::string line, name;
    int sold[6];

    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> name;
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            iss >> sold[i];
        }

        // use name and sold[] as needed...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or, since each line has a fixed format, you can just use `operator>>` directly on the file stream, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("nomefile.txt");
    std::string name;
    int sold[6];

    while (iss >> name)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            iss >> sold[i];
        }

        // use name and sold[] as needed...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, I would probably opt for using a `std::vector` containing elements of a `struct` type that holds the data for each line, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

struct SaleInfo
{
    std::string carName;
    int carsSold[6];
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, SaleInfo &sale)
{
    in >> sale.carName;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        in >> sale.carsSold[i];
    }
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("nomefile.txt");
    std::vector<SaleInfo> sales;
    SaleInfo sale;

    while (file >> sale) {
        sales.push_back(sale);
    }

    // use sales ss needed...

    return 0;
}
```