# Inserting a text file into a 2D Vector c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Using the file called text.txt for example as command-line argument input, How would I create a file object and load the file into a 2D vector of vector>? Any help would be great, thanks!
Here's the code I have so far just checking the command line, but I'm not sure how to put it into a 2d Array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //1. Get filename from the command line
    if (argc <= 1) {
        cout << "Error: incorrect number of command line arguments\n"
            "Usage: allwords filename" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Open the file to be read
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    if (!infile) {
        cout << "Error: failed to open <" << argv[1] << ">\n"
            "Check filename, path, or it doesn't exist.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is the format of the file?

Comment: It's just a text file, title with a blank line after, then 12 small paragraph's with spaces inbetween

Comment: @cplusplusnewb He doesn't mean the file type, he means literally how is the text in the file structured

Comment: That's what I described I thought

Comment: it's unclear what you want the result to look like. Is it a vector of "paragraph" vectors?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738882/read-input-separated-by-whitespaces-or-newline) might help with the reading part.

Comment: All we were told is to is to  Create a file object. Load the file into a 2D
vector: vector<vector<char>>. Because then we have to process the 2D vector in a variety of ways like find number of occurrences of the letter "a" in it for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you. It will create a vector where each element is a word in the file in `vector<char>` format.

```
// The list
std::vector<std::vector<char>> text;
std::string word;
// Read entire file
while (infile >> word) {
    // Create the char vector and add it to main vector
    text.push_back(std::vector<char>(word.begin(), word.end()));
}

// Note: need to #include <algorithm> for count
int num_a = 0;
// Check each and every word for 'a'
for (auto word : text) {
    num_a += std::count(word.begin(), word.end(), 'a');
}
std::cout << "there are " << num_a << " a's" << std::endl;

// Vector for comparison
std::vector<char> a{ 'a' };
num_a = 0;
for (auto word : text) {
    num_a += word == a;
}
std::cout << "there word a appears " << count << " times" << std::endl;
```

Comment: while (infile >> word) in this code the >> is giving me an error

Comment: @cplusplusnewb What's the error? I just tried it here and it worked ok....Don't forget to `#include <string>`.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to include <string> when I using doing all the includes...embarrassing lol. 

Do you know how you would then lead into checking all the occurrences of the letter "a" for example.

Comment: @cplusplusnewb You can use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). Will update with example.

Comment: Cool thanks , you are awesome. Is there anything special I have to do with vectors, because say your just doing a regular file input and you have to do the inFile.open("text.txt") then close it, do you have to do that with a 2d vector

Comment: No. You don't _have to_ `close` the file either. When it goes out of scope it will close itself. However, it does not hurt to close it when you are done. Vectors also take care of their own housekeeping. That's why we prefer them to raw arrays.

Comment: Anyway to communicate with you more, you help me understand more then my teacher lol

Comment: There are many really smart people on this site - and most are eager to help. Keep asking questions like this and you will get plenty of good advice.

Comment: Hopefully last question, how would change it to look for the number of occurrences of the word "a" instead of the number of times the letter appears.

Comment: You could create a `vector<char> a{'a'}` and do a comparison. Will update.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp OP is supposed to show an attempt, otherwise you're just doing homework for them. If this is an early college CS course, the professor is gonna know when they see the code.

Comment: Actually he didn't do my homework, he helped a lot, thanks Johnny!

Comment: @RyanHaining That may be true. While the methods I use aren't "advanced" they might be considered beyond "beginner". That's up to OP to determine.